# Error installing lxml in windows 10 x86

Tags: python, windows, package, virtualenv

Hellow! I have problems in a virtualenv in windows 10, when i make `pip install lxml`. I try all I could, but it always fails-

```
Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\robert\entornos\organilab\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Us
rs\\Robert\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_ak6j86r\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\
\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-k_pwc9ol-record\instal
-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\robert\entornos\organilab\include\site\python3.6\lxml
    Building lxml version 3.6.1.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b'"xslt-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\re
ources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resou
ces\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron
resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\is
schematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\res
urces\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\i
o-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\users\robert\
ntornos\organilab\include -IC:\Python36-32\include -IC:\Python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "
IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Pro
ram Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Win
ows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\tem
.win32-3.6\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    creating Users
    creating Users\Robert
    creating Users\Robert\AppData
    creating Users\Robert\AppData\Local
    creating Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program F
les\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windo
s Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\inclu
e\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240
0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit2j5a3cnw.c /FoUsers\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit2j5a3cnw.obj
    xmlXPathInit2j5a3cnw.c
    C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit2j5a3cnw.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such f
le or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    **error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2**

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\robert\entornos\organilab\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Robert\\AppData\\Lo
al\\Temp\\pip-build-_ak6j86r\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();ex
c(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-k_pwc9ol-record\install-record.txt --single-ve
sion-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\robert\entornos\organilab\include\site\python3.6\lxml" failed with error code
1 in C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_ak6j86r\lxml\
```

Comment: Any problem decrypting **make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed**?

Comment: I try to install that packages but its complicated in windows.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install lxml==3.6.0`

Can you run pip command for lxml specific package as it includes wheel, in newer version it is not packaged along. Later you can upgrade package if you need latest package.

Answer (score 0):

Get ready-made wheel from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Download a wheel for you Python version and run

```
pip install lxml‑4.1.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
```

(change the file name to what you download).

Comment: Yeah I downloaded from that web site, installed and get same error later. Could it affect that I have python 2.7 and 3.6 installed?

Comment: Yes, for Python3 the program is called `pip3`.